# Is this code safe from injection?

Tags: mysql, pdo, output

I have updated this question with the code I had in mind to accept the user input. Basically I am trying to make sure this code is safe from SQL injection since it does have user input.

```
<?php
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
?>

<font size="+3" face="Verdana">XXXX</font>
<br><br>
<form name="form" action="XXX.PHP" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" size="60" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
</form>

<table>

<?

$var = $_GET['q'];

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX', $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM XXXX WHERE XXXX LIKE '%$var%' OR XXXX LIKE '%$var%' OR XXXX LIKE '%$var%'");
$stmt->execute(array());

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ( count($result) ) {
foreach($result as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$row['XXXX']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['XXXX']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['XXXX']. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";    
}  
} 
else {
echo "No results found.";
}
} 
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Since your SQL query is a string without any outside values interpolated, it's safe.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Would this be vulnerable to SQL injection if I added a search box to query the database?

I am going to try and learn about HTML injection too.

Comment: @GarrettBurke [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a *specific* vulnerability that relates to changing the shape of an SQL query - this is usually done when the query a string that has been manually built up from variables containing external data. Placeholders - of which there are none here, and hence the `array()` - prevent SQL injection. SQL injection is about *data* (in SQL queries), and not *information* or other semantic use of the data.

Comment: The moment you use any user-provided value into an SQL query, you are exposed to SQL injection. Thus you must be careful and handle user-provided data appropriately. You would use the string in search box into a database query? So you need to take care of the string to avoid any SQL injection

Comment: @Jean Only if one *doesn't* use placeholders, then one is exposed to SQL injection. Placeholders eliminate SQL injection. However, other attacks (e.g. injecting malicious HTML that is later rendered "raw") is still possible. This is *not* SQL injection, even though it may represent another security vulnerability.

Comment: @Jean This is nonsense. You are risking code injection if you use user-supplied data to *build code*, not if you use user-supplied data *at all*. That's why SQL injection is not a problem in the above, but HTML injection is.

Comment: @Tomalak The question is about SQL injection. What, in what I wrote  is nonsense? Can you be more specific? Don't we have to handle data appropriately to avoid SQL injections?

Comment: @Jean Yes, through prepared statements and parameters. Your comment made it sound as if one would be *always* in danger (*"The moment you use any user-provided value into an SQL query, ..."*). And that's just not true. Maybe I misread you, though. -- SQL injection is just one danger. Every code injection vulnerability is dangerous. So pointing out HTML injection here is right even if the OP did not ask for it.

Comment: @Tomalak I agree. I only focussed on the question at hand, but in this context, warning about other related vulnerabilities, as you did, is highly relevant.

Comment: Is HTML injection still something to worry about even if the page is not a forum or blog? It's going to be more of a e-commerce like product search page

Comment: Please make sure to not radically alter a question once posted - it can obsolete answers/comments (after the code-change it *is* possible for injection because you're *not using placeholders*) .. in any case, *always* use proper HTML (or appropriate) escaping. If the data comes from the user, this is very important, but it is *also* important to prevent data from accidentally breaking a page. Do it consistently and avoid surprises.

Answer (score 4):

You only risk SQL injections if you do not handle appropriately the data provided by malicious users.

Since you don't have any user-provided data in your query, you don't fear anything on the SQL injection side.

### Adding a search box

The moment you use any user-provided value into an SQL query, you are exposed to SQL injections. Thus you must be careful and handle user-provided data appropriately. 
You would use the string in search box into a database query, right?

Then you need to take care of the string to avoid any SQL injection

### Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access

As **pst** suggested, using PDO is the recommended way to proceed.

Here are a few good articles on the topic:

- [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)
- [Introduction to PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

### Using mysql_real_escape_string

**is deprecated.** From [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> This extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.
>   See also `MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ` for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_real_escape_string()
> - [PDO::quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: If I was to add a search function using user input, would it then be vulnerable? Say for example my code was something like this:

    SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE phonenumber LIKE '%$var%'

Where $var would be the search term

Comment: @GarrettBurke That would indeed be prone to SQL injection because it *doesn't* use placeholders. Solution: **use placeholders, which PDO provides "for free"**

Comment: Yes, that'd be vulnerable. You'd want to use the docs for PDO::prepare for how to handle it.

Comment: Yes you would be vulnerable if you don't handle the data appropriately.

Comment: @Jean *Add* an example of an *appropriate* way to use *PDO placeholders* and I'll upvote this answer. If you use `mysql_real_escape_string`, I will downvote it :)

Comment: @GarrettBurke pst is right. Here is a tutorial on *Positional and Named Placeholders* http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Positional-and-Named-Placeholders-P551.html

Comment: @pst I added two comprehensive information source to provide a good start, and the reason for your remark: *If you use mysql_real_escape_string, I will downvote it :)*

Comment: @Jean Okay, upvote as promised. This answer would be better if it gave a small example (just a one-liner query/binding) and touched on correct handling of generating HTML ..

Comment: @pst Thanks. Thought I did it more because it was a really good idea than for the upvote. I reached the daily rep limit 3 hours ago.

Comment: I read the article you posted Jean. What is posted there makes sense, but I can't figure out how it would work with a single user query, for example if I had a table with "First Name" as one column, and "Last Name" as another column, and the user searches for "Burke" or "Garrett", I need it to be able to use the same query to search through both columns, and it also must return the right result if they type "Garrett Burke"

Comment: @GarrettBurke In the second link, they show some examples (in the SELECT section). They have an animal table from which they extract the `animal_type` and the `animal_name`. You would proceed the same way, except that you would select `first_name` and `last_name` and your condition wouldn't need to be `*` (that would select all the data) but would be limited to the first name and last name matching Burke Garrett.

Comment: I updated my code to show what I have in mind, I guess I should not have used that example as it's not the real example. In reality I need every column displayed within a row if the query hits a match in the database.

I am checking out the 2nd link now.

Comment: Ok. Then you need to protect $var. For that use PDO::quote. See the link towards PDO::quote in my answer. They provide examples. Maybe we could move to the chat or open a new question (like "How to use PHP's PDO to formulate SQL request") because we are both making a growing list of comments and going off topic (topic is: Is this code safe from injection?)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am going to check out PDO::quote

Comment: My pleasure. Also, take the advices about HTML injections too. Thought off topic *they are* highly relevant.

Comment: I unfortunately can not move the discussion to chat since I only have 16 rep :(

Comment: Maybe an other time then. But you can still ask new questions and find that many people here are alway willing to help. Anyway I believe you have everything you need to get a good start. SQL injection is a difficult topic and there are many subtleties… Here is an article you may enjoy which describes how experts did breach through an unprotected web interface asking for login and password and got full privileged access to the web application. http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html